# Kotlin function argument as suspendable

Tags: kotlin

Currently, I have the following in my code

```
fun use(consumer: (T) -> Unit) {
    consumer(this.value)
}

suspend fun useS(consumer: suspend (T) -> Unit) {
    consumer(this.value)
}
```

These are 2 methods that are actually doing the same. However, I was not able to merge them into one, nor to use overloaded method. In some places my consumer argument is a regular function, on other places it is `suspend` function; I do not have control over that.

Is it possible to have just one method, regardless of my consumer "suspendability"?

EDIT: forgot to mention that `this.value` is `private` and hence using `inline` would not work - still, I am in control of that, so might change the visibility of the `value` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF the code really is as simple as you've provided, simply using the non-suspend version and make it `inline` would solve your issues.

By making it inline (and thus inlining the consumer) it allows the inner block to use the calling environment of the caller. This is why all the library helper functions like [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) can be used in a suspend function and call suspend functions without explicitly being suspend functions themselves.

Comment: Make sense, just forgot to mention that `this.value` is private for the class. I might make it public for this purpose.

Comment: You can make it `internal` and use the `@PublishedApi` annotation to make it available for inline methods, whilst still disallowing direct access